# How can you use scikit-learn to do PCA on a 9 band raster image?

Tags: python, raster, remote-sensing, scikit-learn, pca

I would like to do a PCA on a 9band raster image to reduce the total number of inputs bands to 3. However, I'm not able to do it as I don't think I understand what sklearn is doing in its PCA.

Some code:

```
import skimage, rasterio, numpy, os
from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_raster, reshape_as_image

infile = r"C:/.../.../Sentinelimage9bands.tif"
im = rasterio.open(infile)
arr = im.read()
pca = sklearn.decomposition.pca(n_components = 3)
arrs = reshape_as_image(arr)
pca.fit(arrs)
```

Resulting error: "Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2"

How am I supposed to do the PCA if it can't accept more than 2 dimensions? Moreover, if I flatten the array into 1 dimension, how will I know the explained variance from each band?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question, `arr` is likely a numpy array with size `(9, ny, nx)` (where `ny` and `nx` are the size of the image in pixels across). Most sklearn functions take a 2D array (often called `X`), with features (in your case, bands) as columns and samples (or pixels) as rows. So you'd have to reshape `arr` to be `(9, nx*ny)`. Then it should work.